# Nvidia-settings won't detect second monitor

Tags: nvidia, 13.04, multiple-monitors, monitor

I appreciate there are a lot of similar questions to this already but I can't seem to fix it following any current threads.

I have installed 64bit Ubuntu 13.04 and installed the Nvidia drivers as per this thread:
http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/ubuntu-quetzal-nvidia.html

The drivers seem to be working correctly and I can access the nvidia-settings, but *detect displays* does not detect my second monitor (actually an LG TV if it matters connected through HDMI) from either nvidia-settings or the standard display option.

Some of the other threads mention editing the *etc/X11/xorg.conf* file but it doesn't exist on my system, at that location at least.

Any help would be appreciated, and thanks in advance.

Rob

Comment: Still no progress this end guys, any guesses?

Comment: I do get an Ubuntu background on the second monitor: like this one: http://i55.photobucket.com/albums/g139/Yoyomega/0114111510.jpg but still no luck detecting it or using it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the problem stemmed from the fact that I had my main monitor plugged directly into the GPU, and my second plugged into the HDMI port on my motherboard (with integrated graphics).

This was not a problem in Windows but neither the NVIDIA settings nor default Displays settings detected the second monitor, but I noticed that the second was the default display when I was using a VC for example.

So I switched around come cables, and plugged both directly into the GPU, and now I have both monitors set up correctly :)